# Regex to ignore matching if starting or ending with certain pattern

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Need to write a regex which ignore both of the two patterns:

Pattern 1 - Should **ignore** if the `text` is starting with `<` && ending with `>`
Pattern 2 - Should **ignore** if `text` is written inside this pattern: `[...](text)`

Examples:

- Should match `<text`, because it doesn't end with `>`
- Should match `text>`, because it doesn't start with `<`
- Should **not** match `<text>`, because it fulfills Pattern 1
- Should **not** match `[...Anything...](text)`, because it fulfills Pattern 2
- Should match `(text)`, because in beginning it doesn't have `[...]`
- Should match `[(text)`, because it does not satisfies any of the patterns.

Comment: you can do Pattern 1 with negative lookarounds. But it's hard to do Pattern 2 in regular expressions.

Comment: I guess these test cases are relevant too: _"Should not match `<text` because `[...Anything...](text)` fulfills Pattern 2"_ and _"Should not match `(text)` because `<text>` filfills Pattern 1"_, right?

Comment: @TedLyngmo `<text` & `(text)` will match because it does not follow any of the two patterns. I just wanted to restrict these two patterns, other than everything can be matched. Thanks

Comment: @ArijitKundu Sure, that pattern isn't what I wondered about. My question is really: Should a line be rejected if it contain either `<text>` OR `[...](text)`? That's how I interpreted it. You can check my demo. Does it do the right thing?

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you so much efforts, in my usecase the `text` is actually a link. I created a regex for the that where if a link is within the patterns. I want to ignore it. But unable to do it. Can you take a look: https://regex101.com/r/eoS985/1

Could you concatenate your regex with these to make sure the last three examples also do not matches

Comment: Hmm, it looks like all in the valid group matches and all in the invalid groups don't. I'm not sure what three you mean? Perhaps you could update the question with a groups of syrings that should match and a group that shouldn't match?

Comment: Sorry, could you check the link once more: https://regex101.com/r/Ec6W7z/1

Comment: Well, in that case, you could just add an anchor, `^`, at the start of the line, but I doubt that's what you mean. You need to make your example strings more complex/real-life like if it's going to work.

Comment: But then it ignores all the matches where the match is not in the beginning of the line.

Comment: My point exactly. Make examples where just adding `^` (or anything else as simple) will not seem to fix it. Unrelated: Your URL matching seems to be very complex. Does it need to be? Would it match URLs you don't want if it was simplified?

Comment: Btw, why is `(https://www.google.com)` invalid? According to the rules in your question, it should be valid. Assuming that was a mistake, then following the same pattern as in my answer, a start could be [this](https://regex101.com/r/Yz2hFf/1). I didn't bother making URL matchings in the negative lookahead there, but you get the point.

Comment: @ArijitKundu Do you have any feedback on the second regex in my answer? If that doesn't work, then _please_ update the question and put two categories of test strings in your question: One that the regex should match and one that it should not match.

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted it with these added testcases in mind:

- Should not match `<text` because `[...Anything...](text)` fulfills Pattern 2
- Should not match `(text)` because `<text>` filfills Pattern 1

```
^(?!.*(<text>|\[.*\]\(text\))).*(<text|text>|\(text\))
```

- `(?!.*(<text>|\[.*\]\(text\)))` - Negative lookahead for either `<text>` or `[...anything...](text)`.
- In neither is found, then `.*(<text|text>|\(text\))` matches either `<text`, `text>` or `(text)`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gtuXAn/1)

If it's not required that `text` is either `<text`, `text>` or `(text)` it can be simplified to only the negative lookahead part:

```
^(?!.*(<text>|\[.*\]\(text\)))
```

add `.*text` to the end if `text` is actually required to exist in the string.

---

Applied to your URL examples, I would do it a bit differently.

- First a positive lookahead to match on a URL. I haven't tampered with your URL matching regex more than that I removed a redundant `{1}`:

  ```
  ^(?=.*((https?:\/\/|www\.)([\da-z\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6}|[\d\.]+)([\/:?=&#][\da-z\.-]+)*[\/\?]?))
  ```
- Then I'd use this match in the negative lookahead:

  ```
  (?!.*(<\1>|\[.*\]\(\1\)))
  ```

Combined you'd get:

```
^(?=.*((https?:\/\/|www\.)([\da-z\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6}|[\d\.]+)([\/:?=&#][\da-z\.-]+)*[\/\?]?))(?!.*(<\1>|\[.*\]\(\1\)))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6cGw9c/1)